# getActivity()でnullが返ってくる

Tags: android

下記のコードの`getActivity().runOnUiThread`で`Null`が返ってきてしまいます。
なので、`getActivity`の値をログで確認してみると、`Null`になっていました。
これはどうしてなのでしょうか？今まで普通に`getActivity`を使ってたように使っているつもりなのですが......。

```
public class testDialog extends DialogFragment {
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                }
            });
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [public final getActivity()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity())
>   Return the Activity this fragment is currently associated with.

ドキュメントにもありますように、`getActivity()`とは、**現在`Fragment`と関連付けられている`Activity`**　を返すメソッドになります。

「現在関連付けられている」の定義とは、[`Fragment`のライフサイクル](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)のうち`onAttach()`から`onDetach()`までを指します。

ライフサイクルの終了した`Fragment`が`Activity`への参照を持ち続けると、メモリリークに繋がるためです。また、`setRetainInstance(true)`をコールした`Fragment`は、複数の`Activity`と関連付けられることもあります。

そのため、`Runnable#run()`のような非同期処理で`getActivity()`を呼び出すべきではありません。取得した`Activity`が想定したものとは限りませんし、`DialogFragment`のような短命な`Fragment`では`null`が返却されます。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
RunnableでgetActivityを呼び出すべきではないのですね。
情報ありがとうございます。やり方を変えたいと思います。

Answer (score 0):

この`runnable`が実行される前にダイアログが閉じられていたり、アプリが終了していたりしませんか？もしくは、ダイアログが表示される前に実行されていたりしませんか？

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。ダイアログが閉じていたり、アプリが終了しているということはなかったです。